# WriterT monad transformer

Tags: haskell, monads, monad-transformers

I'm following this tutorial "Monad Transformers Step by Step"

http://www.cs.virginia.edu/~wh5a/personal/Transformers.pdf

and the code in eval5 function from section 2.5

```
type Name = String

data Exp = Lit Integer
         | Var Name
         | Plus Exp Exp
         | Abs Name Exp
         | App Exp Exp
         deriving (Show)

data Value = IntVal Integer
           | FunVal Env Name Exp
           deriving (Show)         

type Env = Map.Map Name Value   

type Eval5 a = ReaderT Env (ErrorT String 
                           (WriterT [String] (StateT Integer Identity))) a

runEval5 :: Env -> Integer -> Eval5 a -> ((Either String a, [String]), Integer)                       
runEval5 env st ev = 
    runIdentity (runStateT (runWriterT (runErrorT (runReaderT ev env))) st)


eval5 :: Exp -> Eval4 Value
eval5 (Lit i)           = do tick
                             return $ IntVal i

eval5 (Var n)           = do tick 
                             tell [n]
                             env <- ask
                             case Map.lookup n env of 
                                Nothing  -> throwError("unbound variable: " ++ n)
                                Just val -> return val

eval5 (Plus e1 e2)      = do tick
                             e1' <- eval5 e1
                             e2' <- eval5 e2
                             case (e1', e2') of
                                (IntVal i1, IntVal i2) ->
                                    return $ IntVal $ i1 + i2
                                _ -> throwError "type error in Plus"                                

eval5 (Abs n e)         = do tick
                             env <- ask
                             return $ FunVal env n e

eval5 (App e1 e2)       = do tick
                             val1 <- eval5 e1
                             val2 <- eval5 e2
                             case val1 of
                                FunVal env' n body ->
                                    local (const $ Map.insert n val2 env')
                                          $ eval5 body
                                _ -> throwError "type error in App"
```

fails to compile with the message:

```
No instance for (MonadWriter [Name] Identity)
  arising from a use of `tell'
Possible fix:
  add an instance declaration for (MonadWriter [Name] Identity)
In a stmt of a 'do' block: tell [n]
In the expression:
  do { tick;
       tell [n];
       env <- ask;
       case Map.lookup n env of {
         Nothing -> throwError ("unbound variable: " ++ n)
         Just val -> return val } }
In an equation for `eval5':
    eval5 (Var n)
      = do { tick;
             tell [n];
             env <- ask;
             .... }
```

ghc version 7.6.3

Comment: Side note: you may want to [avoid using `WriterT [String]`](http://www.haskellforall.com/2014/02/streaming-logging.html).

Comment: I read this blog post just a few days ago, thanks :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the `tick` function is the same function mentioned in the paper:

```
tick :: Eval5 ()
tick = do n <- get
          put (n+1)
```

There also seems to be some confusion around `Eval4` vs `Eval5` in your monad transformer. The evaluator seems to be written against `Eval4`. Here's the fixed source:

```
import Control.Monad.Reader
import Control.Monad.Writer
import Control.Monad.Error
import Control.Monad.Identity
import Control.Monad.State

import qualified Data.Map as Map

type Name = String

data Exp = Lit Integer
         | Var Name
         | Plus Exp Exp
         | Abs Name Exp
         | App Exp Exp
         deriving (Show)

data Value = IntVal Integer
           | FunVal Env Name Exp
           deriving (Show)

type Env = Map.Map Name Value

type Eval5 a = ReaderT Env (ErrorT String
                           (WriterT [String] (StateT Integer Identity))) a

runEval5 :: Env -> Integer -> Eval5 a -> ((Either String a, [String]), Integer)
runEval5 env st ev =
    runIdentity (runStateT (runWriterT (runErrorT (runReaderT ev env))) st)

tick :: Eval5 ()
tick = do n <- get
          put (n+1)

eval5 :: Exp -> Eval5 Value
eval5 (Lit i) = do
  tick
  return $ IntVal i

eval5 (Var n) = do
  tick
  tell [n]
  env <- ask
  case Map.lookup n env of
     Nothing  -> throwError("unbound variable: " ++ n)
     Just val -> return val

eval5 (Plus e1 e2) = do
  tick
  e1' <- eval5 e1
  e2' <- eval5 e2
  case (e1', e2') of
     (IntVal i1, IntVal i2) ->
         return $ IntVal $ i1 + i2
     _ -> throwError "type error in Plus"

eval5 (Abs n e) = do
  tick
  env <- ask
  return $ FunVal env n e

eval5 (App e1 e2) = do
  tick
  val1 <- eval5 e1
  val2 <- eval5 e2
  case val1 of
     FunVal env' n body ->
         local (const $ Map.insert n val2 env')
               $ eval5 body
     _ -> throwError "type error in App"
```

On an aside there is a composite monad transformer called [RWS](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/mtl-2.1.2/docs/Control-Monad-RWS-Lazy.html) ( Reader/Writer/State ) which does exactly what your stack does. Using it can simplify the unrolling code quite a bit.

```
type EvalRWST a = RWS Env [String] Integer a

runEvalRWS :: Env -> Integer -> EvalRWST a -> (a, Integer, [String])
runEvalRWS env st ev = runRWS ev env st
```

Comment: Oh my. I just messed up with eval5 type signature. It should be eval5 :: Exp -> Eval5 Value, not eval5 :: Exp -> Eval4 Value.

Comment: I looked at RWS transformer, if I want to add error monad to it, should write this: type Eval6 a = ErrorT String (RWS Env [String] Integer) a. This type would be identical in functionality to Eval5, but runEval6 would have type Env -> Integer -> Eval6 a -> (Either String a, Integer, [String]). Am I right?

Comment: If you need an Error in it you can use the RWST transformer and put the Error at the bottom of the stack in the ``m`` type variable of the signature.

``type EvalRWST a = RWST Env [String] Integer Error a`` and change the ``runRWS`` to ``runRWST``.

Comment: But Error is not a type, it's a type class. You can't use it like that, can you? 
`Kind mis-match
    The fourth argument of 'RWST' should have kind '* -> *',
    but 'Error' has kind '* -> Constraint'`

Comment: If you want to use the ErrorT transformer then use it like you did in your example with an Identity: 

``type EvalRWST a = RWST Env [String] Integer (ErrorT Error Identity) a``. To unroll it use: ``runIdentity . runErrorT . evalRWST``.